# Como funciona o AudioContext?

Tags: javascript, áudio

Dei uma olhada na MDN, mas não entendi muito bem a sua funcionalidade...

- Pra que serve?
- Como usar?
- Qual a diferença em relação ao Audio? Devem ser usados juntos?
- Ele é necessário, por exemplo, para compatibilidade?

Answer (score 0):

Antes do elemento  HTML5, era necessário o Flash ou outro plug-in.
Embora o áudio na Web não exija mais um plug-in, a tag de áudio traz
algumas limitações significativas para a implementação de coisas mais complexas
como jogos sofisticados e aplicativos interativos, como um editor de partitura.

Esse artigo pode ser interessante:
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/